# ASP.NET Core Web API GlobalQueryFilter with IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a multi-tenant ASP.NET Core application where I need to implement global query filters based on the current user's credentials stored in the HttpContext. I'm using Entity Framework Core's global query filter feature to apply filtering to entities such as Account, Category, Transaction, and Budget based on the UserId.

Here's a simplified version of my code snippet:

```cs
private void SetGlobalQueryFilters(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    string userId = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?
        .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value ?? string.Empty;

    if (!Guid.TryParse(userId, out Guid result))
    {
        result = Guid.Empty;
        _logger.LogWarning("Unable to parse user id from HTTP context");
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.UserId == result);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.UserId == result);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.UserId == result);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Budget>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.UserId == result);
}
```

The code works fine when the HttpContext is available, but during migrations, the HttpContext is not present, leading to an exception. To handle this situation, I want to ensure that no data is leaked in case the HttpContext is not accessible.

My question is:

- What is the best approach to handle situations where the HttpContext
  is not available during migrations or in other cases?
- Is using a sentinel value like 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 as a default
  value for filtering when the UserId is unavailable a clean and
  acceptable solution?

Any suggestions or insights on how to handle this scenario in a more robust and clean manner would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Always avoid this kind of entanglement. A data layer has nothing to do with HTTP requests. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy.

Comment: Agree with Gert Arnold, data layer should be independent.

Comment: Ok, but is your suggestion wrapping httpContext into ITenantService? I can do that, but I will still have the same question since ITenantService is just a wrapper. My question is more towards experience with using global query filter for multi-tenancy. Another approach is to have WHERE clauses on every db call.

Comment: I haven't tried this before, But maybe it is also a solution, You can create a method like: private void ApplyQueryFilter<TEntity>(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, string userId)
    
    {
        var entityBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(x => false); // No data should be returned
        }else
        {
            entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(x => x.UserId == result);
        }
    } Then in SetGlobalQueryFilters, just call this method for each entity.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best approach to handle situations where the HttpContext is not available during migrations or in other cases?

Do not inject the IHttpContextAccessor directly via the constructor of the DbContext, inject the IServiceProvider instead:

```
public MyDbContext(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

> Is using a sentinel value like 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 as a default value for filtering when the UserId is unavailable a clean and acceptable solution?

If your _httpContextAccessor is null and you can be sure that there is no other scenario than a migration just don't apply the QueryFilters at all. If your _httpContextAccessor is not null and you cannot retrieve a userId from it throw an exception because you most likely have an authorization problem.